# xcode, objective c, read contents of audio (.WAV, PCM encoded) file into a C integer array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, wav, lame

I am working on an app that **captures an audio recording** and converts it into `mp3`.

i am using the **LAME open source library** in `C` to convert into `mp3`. it has a function which requires the entire stream of integers representing the **PCM encoded** .wav file as an `integer array`.

This is my first project ever on iphone development and I am not able to figure out how can i read the contents of the **wav** file (which is supposed to be nothing but `stream of integers`) into a `C style array`?

please help.

Neerav

Comment: i had to leave the project on the same day so never got back to this question. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective C, you can easily read from a file into an `NSData` object with something like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData datawithContentsOFFile:filename];
```

You can then get the number of bytes in that object and allocate a C style integer array of matching size like this:

```
NSUInteger length = [data length];
int *cdata = (int*)malloc(length);
```

and copy the bytes out of the `NSData` object into the C array like this:

```
[data getBytes:(void*)cdata length:length];
```

Don't forget to free the memory in the C array when you're done with it.

```
free(cdata);
```

Comment: i had to leave the project on the same day so never got back to this question. sorry. will surely remember this.

Comment: That does not work for me :S it reads "52494646 285f0100 57415645", from "5249 4646 24b0 0000 5741 5645". Why does it combine every 2x4 digit data?